# Issue on Adding and Removing a Class in a Group of element Continuously

Tags: jquery

Can you please let me know how I can Add a Class to each of `.col-md-3` and remove it after 5 seconds Continuously?

```js
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">Mapping</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Coding</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Network</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Application</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
body{
  padding:25px;
}
.red{
    color:red
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
setInterval(function(){
   
      $(".col-md-3").each(function(){
         $(this).toggleClass('red')
    });
}, 2000)
```

As you can see this add the class to all of the element but I need to do this one by one

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval & https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: issue? I cannot see your jquery code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o4k5mcdy/1/

Comment: @Arun , thanks Arun but you are adding the classes to all elements at once but I need to add and remove to each of them one by one after

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/o4k5mcdy/2/

Comment: The problem is I cant update the snippet let me re insert it again

Comment: Ok Guys I inserted the new code snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) like

```js
setInterval(function() {
  $curr = $curr.removeClass('red').next();
  if (!$curr.length) {
    $curr = $('.col-md-3').first()
  }
  $curr.addClass('red');
}, 2000);
var $curr = $('.col-md-3').first().addClass('red');
```

```css
body {
  padding: 25px;
}
.red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Mapping</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Coding</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Network</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Application</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use following snippet:

```js
setInterval(function(){
    var $next = $('.col-md-3.red + .col-md-3').length ? $('.col-md-3.red + .col-md-3') : $('.col-md-3').first(); 
    $('.col-md-3.red').add($next).toggleClass('red')
}, 2000);
$('.col-md-3').first().addClass('red'); // should be set in HTML markup instead
```

```css
body{
  padding:25px;
}
.red{
    color:red
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">Mapping</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Coding</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Network</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">Application</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following solution:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $curr = $curr.removeClass('red').next();
    if (!$curr.length) {
        $curr = $('.col-md-3').first()
    }
    $curr.addClass('red');
}, 5000);
var $curr = $('.col-md-3').first().addClass('red');
```

Refer this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/ap4hdkLy/

Comment: thanks for clarification. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function that finds the active `.red` class. Find it's index and add one to it. If it reaches the number of `.col-md-3` items or isn't found at all, set the next index to zero.

```js
function loopClass() {
    var col = $('.row .col-md-3');
    var active = $('.row .red').index();
    var next = 0;
    if( active != -1 && active != ( col.length - 1 ) )
        next = active + 1;
    col.removeClass('red').eq( next ).addClass('red');
}

$(function(){ 
    setInterval( function() { loopClass(); }, 500); 
});
```

```css
.red{ color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Mapping</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Coding</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Network</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Application</div>
  </div>
</div>
```